# Unity, Play Store Warnings : Cleartext traffic allowed for all domains and Your app accepts user certificates when verifying secure connections

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I just published an update for my android game to play store,
and I found these two warnings :

> Cleartext traffic allowed for all domains Your app's Network Security
> Configuration allows cleartext traffic for all domains. This could
> allow eavesdroppers to intercept data sent by your app. If that data
> is sensitive or user-identifiable it could impact the privacy of your
> users.
>
> Consider only permitting encrypted traffic by setting the
> cleartextTrafficPermitted flag to false, or adding an encrypted policy
> for specific domains.

and

> Your app accepts user certificates when verifying secure connections.
> Your app's Network Security Configuration allows the use of
> user-specified certificates. This could allow eavesdroppers to
> intercept data sent by your app, or to modify data in transit.
>
> Consider nesting the trust-anchors element that allows user
> certificates inside a debug-overrides element to make sure they are
> only available when android:debuggable is set to true.

as shown in this photo:
[image]

I looked the internet for a solution, and one suggested I should add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"` to `AndroidManifest.xml`

If I were to go for that, I think I should enable "Custom Main Manifest" option in Unity Player / Publishing Settings. as shown here:
[image]

If you managed to solve this, We would really appreciate you sharing your solution. and maybe share your custom AndroidManifest after doing needed mods.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced with this issue in one of our shipped products. We did not add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"` tag to our AndroidManifest.xml file but we did updated our SDKs and error went away.

We updated our Ad SDK to it's latest version. (Including all of the related ad networks)

Hope this helps.

(And yes you need to enable custom AndroidManifest.xml to be able to edit it with your preferred text editor)